# Vim: exrc loads global .vimrc first

Tags: vim

I have the global `.vimrc` file located at `$HOME/.vimrc`, also in some folders I have local `.vimrc` files (option exrc is set).

When I run vim, I expect local `.vimrc` to be loaded. Unfortunately, vim doesn't work that way. It loads global `.vimrc` first and then local version (if it exists).

Is there any workaround for this? Is it possible to load only local version when it's presented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly source a custom `vimrc` like this:

```
$ vim -Nu /path/to/custom/.vimrc
```

In this case, the `exrc` option doesn't matter.

To source a `vimrc` that's right here in your working directory, do:

```
$ vim -Nu .vimrc
```

See `$ vim --help`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try some plugin, e.g. [vim-addon-local-vimrc](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-local-vimrc) or [vim-localvimrc](https://github.com/embear/vim-localvimrc)